# gcm send and get push payload data with web (chrome)

Tags: javascript, push-notification, chrome-gcm

I try send data to gcm and in client side receive it.
every things is work and push is receive but data filed is null, try with postman like this :

**URL**: `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`

**Headers:**

```
Authorization: key=<your-api-key>
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Body**

```
{
  "collapse_key": "score_update",
  "time_to_live": 108,
  "delay_while_idle": true,
  "data": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  "registration_ids":["eaFbvFT64EQ:APA91bEfdq8QDTU2XbQ3V1bhC5UnMz2ZKWUQokq3Ta79Vg_2-Z8rnI6MFCxko6hVt3EoSQoqa24-ddjy8iSbxoP36rvXoGcPqsMQWFjzM5mz6K8tPbfoL2zEEfDxvcXajlb_-vw2vmpv"]
}
```

this way work and send push to client with registration_ids but data filed is null.

and try with another way with **to** instead of registration_ids like this :

```
{
     "to":"eaFbvFT64EQ:APA91bEfdq8QDTU2XbQ3V1bhC5UnMz2ZKWUQokq3Ta79Vg_2-Z8rnI6MFCxko6hVt3EoSQoqa24-ddjy8iSbxoP36rvXoGcPqsMQWFjzM5mz6K8tPbfoL2zEEfDxvcXajlb_-vw2vmpv",
     "data": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}
```

and like last way push is receive with null data

I find https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo project and implement it.
this project work very well but in this project payload data is encrypted like this :

**Headers:**

```
Authorization: key=<your-api-key>
Content-Type: application/json
Encryption: salt=L_da9h_5eIPS1c0gNV3fOQ
Crypto-Key: dh=BPDpQTlRDuk8DBFB3LxuTSnevgZGla7g8-LrTRSvUkPiU_ZsQVppocib1lFTYKP33bENL_gaMahaEXinMuYwu-c
```

**Body**

```
{
    "to":"fE5h8Q6gtno:APA91bEO-_LLDOIGMStAxR9J58RwA5fOSdvwVKNYkBnq7Xohm5kf-b4Gc4iq6BzrwEIgZxsKb3EKCtAsQgS34sKWpVEzX_gWx7OpCUuzKRqg50zOt2TjMR1KjHYwV3EkiE0BUh6JS-qu",
    "raw_data":"NBpw3QkilspdNClRE1k1CYsg1wHT3Q=="

}
```

**question :**

1- how to send gcm push message with payload data without encrypt

2- What's the difference between `to` param and  `register_ids` param